# Inequality regarding strong convex domain

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, differential-geometry, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Suppose $\Omega\subset\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, be a bounded, strongly convex domain (with $0\in\Omega$). Is the following inequality true?

$$
C_2\left|x-y\right|^2\leq\left|\frac{x}{|x|}-\frac{y}{|y|}\right|^2\leq C_1\left|x-y\right|^2, \forall x,y\in b\Omega.
$$
$C_1,C_2$ are positive constants not depending on $x,y$.

Comment: What’s your attempt, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this becomes false as soon as $x$ is a positive rescaling of $y$ (i.e. $x=\alpha y$ for some $\alpha>0$), as the middle term becomes $0$.

Comment: @WillowWisp I think that situation never arises since your domain is strongly convex. The half line can only intersect the boundary at a single point.

Comment: @Zackmath oops I completely missed that this was on the boundary of $\Omega$, my bad

Comment: @user1176589 I was trying by triangle inequality. I think Right-hand inequality can be achieved. But the left one is troubling.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be true. I don't think it is necessary to assume that $\Omega$ is strongly convex (but convex, open containing the origin, and bounded are all important). Most of the following is just repeating standard arguments about the Minkowski functional.

Let $\mu_{\Omega}$ be the [Minkowski functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional) of $\Omega$,
$$
\mu_{\Omega}(x) = \inf \lbrace t > 0 : x \in t \, \Omega\rbrace.
$$
The important properties of $\mu_{\Omega}$ we'll need are that it's sublinear, i.e., $\mu_{\Omega}(x + y) \leq \mu_{\Omega}(x) + \mu_{\Omega}(y)$, which follows from the convexity of $\Omega$, and positively homogeneous, i.e., $\mu_{\Omega}(\alpha x) = \alpha \mu_{\Omega}(x)$ when $\alpha \geq 0$. (These properties characterize a [sublinear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublinear_function).)

I'm going to take $x, y \in S_1$, so that the corresponding points in the $\partial \Omega$ are $x/\mu_{\Omega}(x)$ and $y/\mu_{\Omega}(y)$. (Thus my notation does not agree with yours; I found it simpler to work this way.)

First we establish the equivalence of $\mu_{\Omega}$ and $|\cdot|$.

Write $B_1$ to denote the ball of radius $1$ about the origin (in the norm $|\cdot|$). If we let
$$
  m = \sup \lbrace s: s \, \Omega \subseteq B_1 \rbrace \qquad \text{ and } \qquad M = \inf \lbrace s: B_1 \subseteq s \, \Omega \rbrace,
$$
then $m > 0$ since $\Omega$ is bounded, and $M < \infty$ since $\Omega$ is an open neighborhood of the origin. Moreover, for $x \in S^1$ we then have
$$
  m \leq \mu_{\Omega}(x) \leq M.
$$

Since $\mu_{\Omega}$ is positively homogenous, it follows that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$
  m |x| \leq \mu_{\Omega}(x) \leq M |x|. 
$$

We will do the two inequalities separately.

##### Right inequality.

**Lemma.** If $\alpha, \beta \geq r \geq 0$ and $x, y \in S_1$ then $|\alpha x - \beta y| \geq r |x - y|$.

*Proof*. This just says that the distance between two points on the rays through $x$ and $y$ is minimized when both points are as close to the origin as possible. $\square$

By the lemma, for all $x, y \in S_1$ we have
$$
 \frac{1}{M}|x - y| \leq \left| \frac{x}{\mu_{\Omega}(x)} - \frac{y}{\mu_{\Omega}(y)} \right|,
$$
which takes care of the right side of your desired inequality.

##### Left inequality.

To do the left side, note that, because $\mu_{\Omega}$ is sublinear,
$$
  \mu_{\Omega}(x) = \mu_{\Omega}(x - y + y) \leq \mu_{\Omega}(x - y) + \mu_{\Omega}(y)
$$
and hence
$$
  \mu_{\Omega}(x) - \mu_{\Omega}(y) \leq \mu_{\Omega}(x - y).
$$
Since the same holds with $x$ and $y$ switched, it follows that
$$
  |\mu_{\Omega}(x) - \mu_{\Omega}(y)| \leq \max \lbrace \mu_{\Omega}(x - y), \mu_{\Omega}(y - x) \rbrace \leq M |x-y|.
$$
We estimate
\begin{align*}
  \left| \frac{x}{\mu_{\Omega}(x)} - \frac{y}{\mu_{\Omega}(y)} \right| &\leq \left| \frac{x}{\mu_{\Omega}(x)} - \frac{y}{\mu_{\Omega}(x)} \right| + \left| \frac{y}{\mu_{\Omega}(x)} - \frac{y}{\mu_{\Omega}(y)} \right| \\
  &= \frac{1}{\mu_{\Omega}(x)} |x - y| + |y| \left| \frac{\mu_{\Omega}(y) - \mu_{\Omega}(x)}{\mu_{\Omega}(x) \mu_{\Omega}(y)} \right| \\
  &\leq \frac{1}{m}|x - y| + \frac{M}{m^2}|x - y| \\
  &= \frac{m + M}{m^2} |x - y|,
\end{align*}
which is the left side of your desired inequality.

Comment: thanks a lot. This seems correct. I was actually thinking in the direction of support function, which is Minskowaski functional for the polar of \Omega but did not know about the lemma.Thanks a lot for pointing it out. Do you know any formal reference for the lemma?

Comment: No formal reference for the lemma, but this is just plane geometry. If you want to give a formal proof, you can square the left side and notice that the partials $\partial_\alpha, \partial_\beta$ don't vanish on $\alpha, \beta \geq r$, and the function goes to $\infty$ as $\alpha, \beta \to \infty$, so the minimum must be at the boundary point $\alpha = \beta = r$. (But honestly a picture works fine here since everything is happening in the plane spanned by $x, y$.)

Comment: Got it. Thanks!